# Why does my simple select SQL query fail?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

as part of an inner query I need to select  the latest department number (dept_no) where each employee (emp_no) has worked. Note, some employees have worked in multiple departments.  The name of this table is dept_emp.

It seems very simple (and probably is), but I haven't been able to figure it out. This is one of the queries I have tried

```sql
SELECT dept_no, emp_no, from_date
FROM dept_emp
GROUP BY emp_no
HAVING MAX(from_date);
```

This doesn't return the right results. for employee "10010" it returns dept_no "d004" and from_date "1996-11-24" while I expected "d006" and "2000-06-26"

Can anyone suggest a working query to me?

[image]

Comment: You have a malformed query and MySQL should produce an error.  Your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` have incompatible columns.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. Is there a way I can rewrite it so that it will run correctly? It does run, but it doesn't return the right output.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is malformed. If MySQL accepts it you are probably running MySQL 5.x. MySQL 8.x does not accept those malformed queries by default anymore.

In order to get the rows you want you can use a subquery. For example:

```
select
  d.dept_no, 
  d.emp_no, 
  d.from_date
from dept_emp d
join (
  select emp_no, max(from_date) as max_from_date 
  from dept_emp 
  group by emp_no
) m on m.emp_no = d.emp_no
   and m.max_from_date = d.from_date
```